# Remote debugging tomcat with OpenShift

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, openshift, remote-debugging

I am using openshift for my tomcat webapp. I am able to run the app but unable to debug it. As openshift starts tomcat in debug mode, I was expecting I'll be able to debug.

**Host:**

```
$OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP
```

Value of this is **127.5.20.129** for me which I got from command:

```
rhc port-forward -a {appname}
```

**Port:**

```
$OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT
```

Value is **8080** for me.

I tried above host/port. I tried port 8000 too but nothing works. I am unable to connect from eclipse remote debugger each time.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read through the Developer Portal's pages on Port Forwarding (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html) to make sure that you are using it correctly.  You will want to connect to your local loopback address: 127.0.0.1 along with the correct forwarded port once you have run the port-forwarding command.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I decided to move to VPS plan now and no more using openshift.